# How to invoke a python static method inside class via string method name

Tags: python, introspection

I have a the following strings defined which are specifying a python module name, a python class name and a static method name.

```
module_name = "com.processors"
class_name = "FileProcessor"
method_name = "process"
```

I would like to invoke the static method specified by method_name variable.

How do i achieve this in python 2.7+

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849576/how-to-call-a-static-method-of-a-class-using-method-name-and-class-name) might be of some assistance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function to import module by giving module name as string.

Use [`getattr(object, name)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access names from an object (module/class or [anything](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html))

Here u can do

```
module = __import__(module_name)
cls = getattr(module, claas_name)
method = getattr(cls, method_name)
output = method()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use importlib for this.
Try `importlib.import(module +"." + class +"."+ method)`

Note that this concatenated string should look exactly like if you would import it via import module.class.method

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# you get the module and you import
module = __import__(module_name)

# you get the class and you can use it to call methods you know for sure
# example class_obj.get_something()
class_obj = getattr(module, class_name)

# you get the method/filed of the class
# and you can invoke it with method() 
method = getattr(class_obj, method_name)
```