# Dynamically call staticmethod in Python

Tags: python, instance, callable

I have a python object that has various attrs, one of them is `check=None`.

```py
class MenuItem:
    check: bool = True
```

During the `__init__()` process, it parses it's own attrs and looks if they are callable. If so, it calls the function, and replaces it's instance variable with the result of the function:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.request = ...
        if callable(self.check):
            self.check = self.check(self.request)
```

The purpose is to have subclasses that may replace class attrs by lambda functions:

```
class MainMenuItem(MenuItem):
    check = lambda request: request.user.is_authenticated
```

So far, so good. But as the calling of instance methods implicitly adds `self` as first parameter, I would have to write every lambda (or external function) as `lambda self, request: ...` - external functions must be `def check_superuser(self, request): ...` - which IMHO looks bad.

Is there a way in Python to call a function from a method *"as staticmethod"*?
Like

```py
if callable(self.check):
    self.check = staticmethod(self.check)(self.request)
```

(this obviously doesn't work)

Any hint's welcome. Do I completely think wrong?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849576/how-to-call-a-static-method-of-a-class-using-method-name-and-class-name

Comment: Are you maybe looking for an impedance matcher, which discards 1st arg (`self`) when dispatching to the "real" lambda function? Also, consider using named functions instead of lambdas. For one thing, you can `@decorate` them.

Comment: in which part of `MenuItem` the `check` variable becomes callable?

Comment: @JuanIsFree, no, I can't declare the attribute as staticmethod in the first place. @cards: in my real code too, it "becomes" callable at declaration time of inherited classes. It's indeed a MenuItem, and eg AdminMenu declares `check=lambda request: request.user.is_superuser`. @J_H: this is way to complicated for this approach. Meanwhile @Antony Hatchkins has answered it already - this is what I sought. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
class A:
    check: bool = True
    def __init__(self):
        self.request = 'request'
        if callable(self.check):
            self.check = self.__class__.check(self.request)

class B(A):
    check = lambda request: len(request)

b = B()
print(b.check)
```

outputs 7

Comment: Thanks. I always tried to fix it with type(self).check(self.request). But obviously this is calling the Metaclass' check method - which is kind of the same, but it did not work properly. Thanks a bunch.